# css bubble does not appear above

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my css bubble. Can you help me please where I have missing. I must have missed a point I do not know.I have tried with z-index, but still not working.but I have to tell you this overflow: hidden I had to use. This is demo: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/AsDgC)

This is **HTML** code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bubble">

    </div>

</div>
```

And this is **CSS** code:

```
.container{
   float:left;
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:100px;
    border:1px solid d8dbdf;
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -o-border-radius:3px;
}
.bubble 
{
position: relative;
width: 550px;
height: auto;
overflow:hidden;
padding: 15px;
background: #f4f4f4;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: #d8dbdf solid 1px;

}

.bubble:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 12px 10px;
border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
top: -5px;
left: 22px;

}

.bubble:before 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 12px 10px;
border-color: #d8dbdf transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
top: -6px;
left: 22px;

}
```

Comment: What are you missing? What doesn't work properly?

Comment: You simply can not use `overflow:hidden` in this situation. You have to find another solution for what you're trying to do with overflow.

Comment: @pstenstrm Because when I click the drop in bubble have a TextBox. if overflow: hidden does remain below the div.that height does not change.

Comment: It is in front but it's being cropped by the container, the height isn't being set by the browser as you may of expected.

Comment: @jeffPowers yes what can i do in this section ? can you tell me little example in my code?

Comment: @MustafaOzturk can you add an example with the textbox in the codepen?

Comment: @pstenstrm of course give me a little time

Comment: @pstenstrm This is example http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/kdlzF

Comment: @JeffPowers can you check in this code what can i do ? http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/kdlzF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set `overflow: hidden;` to the `<form>` tag inside the bubble instead of `.bubble`.

You could also use a clearfix when you can't, or don't want to, use `overflow: hidden;`. Since you use both `before` and `after` on `.bubble` already you still need to apply it to the `<form>` tag.

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

[Codepen example with clearfix](http://codepen.io/pstenstrm/pen/ketFK)